# Is there an opposite of string.format() in python for setting/extracting values from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to parse a string in python to extract values. We know that strings can be formatted from variables like so:

```py
food = {'fruit':'apple',  'vegetable':'carrot'}
sentence = "I ate a {fruit} and a {vegetable} today".format(**food)
```

Is there a way to do the opposite? Extract values from within a know text template? Something like:

```py
food = sentence.extract("I ate a {fruit} and a {vegetable} today")
# food gets set as dictionary {'fruit':'apple',  'vegetable':'carrot'}
```

1. Extracting from string positions isn't good enough because I want to ensure the rest of the sentence is as per the format
2. Stripping text, splitting on text can have unintended consequences for larger sentences with more positional text values to extract

Ideally looking for a nice one-liner one could put in a lambda expression without custom functions. I'm currently doing 2 but I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`parse`](https://pypi.org/project/parse/):

```
>>> from parse import parse
>>> sentence = 'I ate a apple and a carrot today'
>>> template = 'I ate a {fruit} and a {vegetable} today'
>>> parse(template, sentence).named
{'fruit': 'apple', 'vegetable': 'carrot'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done using a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-17):

```
import re
sentence = "I ate a apple and a carrot today"
matches = re.match(r"I ate a (?P<fruit>.*?) and a (?P<vegetable>.*?) today", sentence) 
print(matches.groupdict())
```

will print

```
{'fruit': 'apple', 'vegetable': 'carrot'}
```